# Cannot subscript a value of type [String] with an index of type "UInt32"

Tags: arrays, swift, random

i've been trying to create a code to generate random names. Here it is

```
import UIKit

 let arrayOfNames: [String] = ["Giovanni", "Simone", "Francesco", "Ahmet",       "Valerio", "Federico"]

 let arrayOfsNames: [String] = [" İl Genio", " Lo scemo", " Verga", " Fermi", " Medici", " L'assasino"]

 var casual1 = arc4random_uniform(7)
 var casual2 = arc4random_uniform(7)

 let name = "\(arrayOfNames[casual1]) + \(arrayOfsNames[casual2])"

  name
```

however on the "let name" line it gives me the mistake on the title. Does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Comment: Just convert casual1 and casual 2 into Int using the Int constructor. `Int(arc4random_uniform(7))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use an `Int` to access an array by index

Replace this

```
var casual1 = arc4random_uniform(7)
var casual2 = arc4random_uniform(7)
```

with this

```
var casual1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(7))
var casual2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(7))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry ı'm a newbie.

Comment: @DarioDenizErgün: you mean why an `Int` instead of a `UInt` is required for array index?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 implemented [SE-0202: Random Unification](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md) Thus there is no need to use the imported C function arc4random(). You can now use Swift’s own native random API.
By calling the `random()` method on any numeric type with the range needed

Thus

```
 var casual1 = arc4random_uniform(7)
 var casual2 = arc4random_uniform(7)
```

should be written as.

```
var casual1 = Int.random(in: arrayOfNames.indices)
var casual2 = Int.random(in: arrayOfsNames.indices)
```